# WebBrowser Control throws script error not seen in IE8

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

Explain a little bit easier.

https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/launchCatalog.do?service=audi_parts

If I go to the site through internet explorer 8, everything works fine. 
If I go to the site through WebBrowser control I get the following js error. 
Just do JavaScriptErrorSurpressed impossible. I need to have these scripts executed because they determine the menu navigation

http://prntscr.com/3gfqnu

Any idea how i can fix it on ie8? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Web Browser controls run in IE7 mode. You need to set a registry key so that it will run in IE8 or later mode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation and/or look for FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION on this site.

Beyond that, this site attempts to detect whether it is running inside its own special WebOC hosting application (something named "Etka"). It does so thusly:

```
var isRunningInEtka=window.ActiveXObject && window.external.sendToContainer;
```

The problem here is that `window.external` is assigned in IE but is likely not set in your application. You can assign an object to `window.external` using the [`ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. IE's `external` object does not have a `sendToContainer` method; your application may or may not want one.